# Optimize jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, optimization, plugins

I created a jquery plugin and i was wondering on how to improve/optimize it.
Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yh2ET/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.linkZoomIcon = function(options)
    {
        var opts = $.extend($.fn.linkZoomIcon.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.hover(function ()
            {
                var image = $(this).find('img:first');

                var elContainer = $('<div class="linkZoomOverlayContainer"></div>');
                var elBackground = $('<div class="linkZoomOverlayBackground"></div>');
                var elIcon = $('<div class="linkZoomOverlayIcon"></div>');

                elContainer.width(image.width()).height(image.height())

                $(this).prepend(elContainer);
                elContainer.prepend(elIcon);
                elContainer.prepend(elBackground);
            },
            function ()
            {
                $(this).find('div.linkZoomOverlayContainer').remove();
            });
        });
    };

    $.fn.linkZoomIcon.defaults = {};

})(jQuery);
```

Any thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: This question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have any specific code you think could be optimized?

Comment: Jasper, i think the prepending could be modified? (don't know how…)

Answer (score 0):

```
var opts = $.extend($.fn.linkZoomIcon.defaults, options);
```

This will modify the original defaults. You need to use a new object as the target:

```
var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.linkZoomIcon.defaults, options);
```

Besides that, you might want to use deep cloning:

```
var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.linkZoomIcon.defaults, options);
```